# Retrieve coordinates of selected feature with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am currently working with the the  ArcGIS API for JavaScript and I have delved into ArcGIS API for JavaScript currently for a weeks, so I am not that familiar with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

For now I managed to create a webapplication with a nice Map and a layerlist, so I managed to learn about the basic widgets of ArcGIS API.

However I included code in which whenever I click on an object of the layerlist it will  show an popup and execute a certain function. For my function, I would like to have the location of the selected feature in coordinates (presumably in WGS84 coordinates). I was therefore wondering how I would be able to retrieve the coordinates of the selected feature, in the attributetable of the feature, there are **no longitude and latitude columns** for example, so I was wondering in which other way I would be able to retrieve the coordinates of the selected feature and being able to store it into a variable. (Whether there is a widget for that for example)

I currently use the JavaScript API 4.10 version.
EDIT: The layer is a ***feature layer.***

Answer (score 3):

If you have a [graphic](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Graphic.html) object, you can inspect it's [geometry](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Geometry.html) property. This in turn has a [type](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Geometry.html#type) property which tells you the type of geometry (Point, Polyline, etc)

If `geometry.type === "point"` you know it's a [point](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Point.html), and you can get the `x` and `y` properties. For other geometry types you would need additional logic, e.g. for a polygon you could get the centroid, and for a polyline you could calculate it's mid point.

Comment: Hi Berend, thank for the explanation, unfortunately my layer is a feature layer, I forgot to mention it. But thanks for explaining in case when the object was graphic object.

Comment: That isn't relevant, a featurelayer is based on features, which are of type `graphic`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last comment ('Do you know by any change how I can use the graph object in the Polygon function'), could you explain what you want exactly? Or even better, post a new question?

Comment: @ Berend sorry for the confusion, my question was not that well formulated, what I meant to say is whether I could apply the properties of the polygon function to the graphic object and I managed to do that with the hint you gave (geometry.type) and instead I used geometry.centroid.latitude. Thank you very much for the hint

Comment: @Joy, if Berend's answer helped you find the solution, it means it was useful. You can upvote it. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Tks.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @Berend, I managed get the coordinates of the selected feature by writing the following code.

```
   var latitude=result.graphic.geometry.centroid.latitude;
    var longitude=result.graphic.geometry.centroid.longitude;
```

Therefore after the graphic object using the geometry, centroid and the longitude or latitude properties will results in the value of the longitude and the latitude.